# two y-axes with different scales for two datasets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two datasets (can be combined into a single one) that share common x values, while the y values are different - I want to plot the y values in one dataset and put the y-axis on the left of the plot, while plotting the y values in the other dataset and put the y-axis on the right of the same plot. Of course, the relative scales for the two y-axis values are different (actually should be "adjusted" according to the y values in the first dataset. The points in the two datasets will be in different colors in order to distinguish the two scales.

An example is shown below:

```
d1 = data.frame(x=c(100, 200, 300, 400), y=seq(0.1, 0.4, by=0.1)) # 1st dataset
d2 = data.frame(x=c(100, 200, 300, 400), y=seq(0.8, 0.5, by=-0.1)) # 2nd dataset
p1 = ggplot(data = d1, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
p2 = ggplot(data = d2, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right")
p1
p2
```

In `ggplot2`, I cannot do `p1+p2` as it will show an error message `Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot`. Please help. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Up front, this type of graph is a good example of why it took so long to get a second axis into `ggplot2`: it can very easily be confusing, leading to mis-interpretations. As such, I'll go to pains here to provide multiple indicators of what goes where.

First, the use of [`sec_axis`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html) requires a transformation on the original axis. This is typically done in the form of an intercept/slope formula such as `~ 2*. + 10`, where the period indicates the value to scale. In this case, I think we could get away with simply `~ 2*.`

However, this implies that you need to plot all data on the original axis, meaning you need `d2$y` to be pre-scaled to `d1$y`'s limits. Simple enough, you just need the reverse transformation as what will be used in `sec_axis`.

I'm going to combine the data into a single data.frame, though, in order to use `ggplot2`'s grouping.

```
d1 = data.frame(x=c(100, 200, 300, 400), y=seq(0.1, 0.4, by=0.1)) # 1st dataset
d2 = data.frame(x=c(100, 200, 300, 400), y=seq(0.8, 0.5, by=-0.1)) # 2nd dataset
d1$z <- "data1"
d2$z <- "data2"
d3 <- within(d2, { y = y/2 })
d4 <- rbind(d1, d3)
d4
#     x    y     z
# 1 100 0.10 data1
# 2 200 0.20 data1
# 3 300 0.30 data1
# 4 400 0.40 data1
# 5 100 0.40 data2
# 6 200 0.35 data2
# 7 300 0.30 data2
# 8 400 0.25 data2
```

In order to control color in all components, I'll set it manually:

```
mycolors <- c("data1"="blue", "data2"="red")
```

Finally, the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d4, aes(x=x, y=y, group=z, color=z)) +
  geom_path() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(name="data1", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 2*., name="data2")) +
  scale_color_manual(name="z", values = mycolors) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = mycolors["data1"]),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = mycolors["data1"]),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = mycolors["data2"]),
    axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = mycolors["data2"])
  )
```

[image: sample graphic with two axes]

Frankly, though, I don't like the different slopes. That is, two blocks on the blue axis are 0.1, whereas on the red axis they are 0.2. If you're talking about two vastly different "things", then this may be fine. If, however, the slopes of the two lines are directly comparable, then you might prefer to keep the size of each block to be the same. For this, we'll use a transformation of just an intercept, no change in slope. That means the in-data.frame transformation could be `y = y - 0.4`, and the plot complement `~ . + 0.4`, producing:

[image: another sample graphic with two axes]

PS: hints taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45683665/3358272 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6920045/3358272

Comment: This is actually a great example of why dual-axis plots are so misleading. Plot on the same axis and you'll see the lines do not even cross...the brain cannot help but interpret crossing upwards as one set becoming "greater than", even when values are shown on the axes.

Comment: Agreed. I'm really hoping that this example is really for a real dataset where a second axis is meaningful. But bottom line, I agree, these plots are easily mis-leading.